# DataTable or String as parameter to an ASP.NET 2.0 Web Service method?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I am new to web services and I was just wondering which alternative is better to use to send data to a MS SQL Server database. I've read that strings are limited in size in web service calls to 4 Mb and I am afraid of situations when data will be truncated somewhere along the line. There will be long strings passed to this method. What do you think, should I use a DataTable instead? Thanks a lot!

Comment: A DataTable is serializable and you can pass it to a web service.

Answer (score 1):

The limit of the data you send in the request to the web service can be increased to more than 4MB from web.config:

> Speaking of arbitrary caps on parameter size, here's a tip for those
>   using the .NET Framework. Under the version of the .NET Framework that
>   shipped with Visual Studio .NET Beta 2, the maximum SOAP message size
>   for a Web Service was capped at 4 MB. You can increase that cap by
>   changing the maxRequestLength setting in the httpRuntime section of
>   the Web.Config file for your Web Service. In the example below, the
>   maxRequestLength has been set to 8096 KB:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="8096"
          useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true"
          executionTimeout="45"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Quoted from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480521.aspx